# ui-router child view being multiple named views or unnamed views

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, nested-views, childviews

How to configure in ui-router a parent/children relationship where siblings coexist in parent page? I can't make child state multiple named views working.

This is my parent page:parent.html:

```
<div> I have two child pages: 
  child page1 detail: <ui-view /> and 
  child page2 detail:<ui-view />.  
  I need both pages
</div>
```

I don't know how to or if I should use multiple-named views since multiple named views seem parallel and separable rather than wrapped around by other text like in the code above.

My ui router config:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('parent', {
    url: '/parent',
    templateUrl: 'parent.html'

  })
  .state('parent.children', {
    url: '/children',
    views: {
      'child1': {
        templateUrl: 'child1.html'
      },
      'child2': {
        templateUrl: 'child2.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

The unnamed ui-view only allows one child to be plugged in.

See code in
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gTZIg4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ui-view>`s in your example are incorrect. It's not a self-closing tag and when `ui-view` is used as the element instead of an attribute directive you need a `name` attribute to use named views. If you change your parent.html to the following it should work.

```
<div> I have two child pages: 
  child page1 detail: <ui-view name="child1"></ui-view> and 
  child page2 detail:<ui-view name="child2"></ui-view>.  
  I need both pages
</div>
```

Comment: Than you, Lex!  It works now.  I wanted to vote for your answer but I am not eligible.

Comment: Glad it helped! You should be able to accept it so it will show on the main list as answered if you'd like.